# Why is my output voltage of my 4-20[mA] to 0.8-4[V] converter saturated at 2.9V?

Tags: zener, 4-20ma

I built a 4-20[mA] to 0.8-4[V] converter using a HCNR201 optocoupler. The diagram I used was the shown in the [datasheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HCNR200-HCNR201-High-Linearity-Analog-Optocouplers-DS):

---

[image: 4 mA to 20 mA HCNR200 Receiver Circuit from HCNR200 datasheet]

---

I'm testing this circuit with a 0-5[V] to 4-20[mA] converter sweeping the voltage, but using my portable oscilloscope I got the blue line showing the 0-5[V] or the 4-20[mA] and the yellow line shows the voltage in Vout with a 100 ohm resistor. Suddenly Vout is saturated at 2.9[V]. So I'm wondering why is it saturated at 2.9V? I tried changing resistor, capacitors and the zener diode, but it just saturated at lower voltages.

Scope:

[image: oscilloscope trace]

Comment: steevglex - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) requiring that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). I found what I believe is the source for the copied content & added it for you this time. For the future, please note it's your responsibility to do that. Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

Answer (score 1):

100Ω is **far** too low of a load resistance on the output.

With negligible loading, I would expect it to saturate around 3.6V on the output with a 5.0V supply and 4.1V with a 5.5V supply due to the output stage of the LM158.

Your results are as expected for the heavy load you are applying.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using a different op amp, so you can get the 4 V upper limit while using just a 5 V supply. A properly chosen op amp might be able to drive your 100 Ω load, too.

Comment: My bad! Realizared I don't need that 100Ω, just the voltage output. I removed the load, but it still saturated in 2,9[V].

Answer (score 0):

> I'm testing this circuit with a 0-5[V] to 4-20[mA] converter

1. The loop-powered reciever needs 5.1V to operate. So the compliance voltage must be greater than 5.1V plus wiring losses.

Your test source supplying 4-20mA seems to have a maximum of only 5V.

The component values should be 1% to stay within the amplifier limitations. The optical feedback will compensate for most tolerances. But the Zener diode should engage at 4mA of loop current splitting it equally with the LED. These are things you can measur to help verify.

2. The LM158 needs 1.5V to 2.0 volts of supply headroom. So to get 4V out the supply needs to be 5.5V to 6.0V. This op-amp will probably work but the specs must co-operate. Better op-amps (rail to rail) are available now.